# React router not routing past a certain point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a fitness app, which means I have some nested data that i am using to dynamically generate some pages within pages within pages.

Here is the data i am using along with it's accompanying functions.

```
const data = [
        {
            title: "Routine1",
            days: [
                {
                    title: "Day1",
                    exercises: [
                        {
                            title: "Bench Press"    
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

const dataMap = data.reduce(function (map, routine) {
routine.daysMap = routine.days.reduce(function (daysMap, day) {
    daysMap[day.title] = day
    return daysMap
  }, {})
  map[routine.title] = routine
  return map
}, {})

exports.getAll = function () {
  return data
}

exports.lookupRoutine = function (title) {
  return dataMap[title]
}

exports.lookupDay = function (routine, day) {
  return dataMap[routine].daysMap[day]
}
```

I want to use React Router to go from an index page that displays all the routines, to a page that displays all the days in a routine, to a page that displays all the exercises in that day.

Here is how I have set up my routes to do this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="routine/:routine" components={{ content: Routine, header: RoutineHeader }}>
    <Route path=":day" components={{ content: Day, header: DayHeader }}>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Let's not worry about the header components because they dont really do anything right now. But I will show how I have set up the App, Index, Routine, and Day components. HINT: they are the same...

app component

```
export default class App extends Component {


render() {
    const { content, header } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <header>
          {header || <IndexHeader />}
        </header>
        <div>
          {content || <Index />}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

index component

```
    export default class Index extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <div class="main-container">
        <h2>Routines</h2>
          {data.getAll().map((routine, index) => (
              <Link class="main-link" key={index} to={`/routine/${routine.title}`}>{routine.title}</Link>
          ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Routine component

```
export default class Routine extends Component {
render() {
    const routine = data.lookupRoutine(this.props.params.routine);



return(
            <div class="main-container">
                <h2>{routine.title} Days</h2>
                    {routine.days.map((day, index) => (
                        <Link key={index} class="main-link" to={`/routine/${routine.title}/${day.title}`}>{day.title}</Link>
                    ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Day component

```
export default class Day extends Component {


render() {
        const { routine, day } = this.props.params;
        const dayItem = data.lookupDay(routine, day);

        return(
            <div class="main-container">
                <h2>{dayItem.title} Exercises</h2>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

maybe you want some visuals to help out? ok well here are some visuals, notice that the 2nd picture is the same as the 1st except in the URL, because I have actually clicked on the day.

[Routine1 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffAFB.png)

[What is supposed to be the Day1 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu3JE.png)

**Edit:** to clarify, what I want the app to do, is display all the days in a routine when i click that routine, and display all the exercises in a day when i click that day. right now it only goes down one level to show all the days in the routine.

Comment: So what is it currently doing?  What do you want it to do?  What's the issue you're having?

Comment: Just made a short edit to clarify, I want to go to a page that will eventually show all the exercises in a specific day when you click on that day, but right now clicking on a day does nothing except update the URL.

Comment: So the Routine route is correctly showing all Days, but the Days route is only showing one exercise?

Comment: Right now nothing happens when i click on a day, it stays on the page showing all the routines, except the URL is updating to show /routine/{routine-title}/{day-title}

Comment: Try adding {this.props.children} into the render method of your routine component.

Comment: Adding {this.props.children to the routine render method doesn't change anyhting.

Another update though, I just installed the react chrome dev tools, and it seems that the params of the routine component are updating to include the day param, which is from the day component, but the page is not showing the day component.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.

What I was doing wrong was nesting the day components in the routine components. The App component is the one that is accepting the conent: and header: components, and since I nested days within routines, the App, which is essentially the view, was not updating because it wasn't finding the day components.

The correct routing looks like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
 <Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="routine/:routine" components={{ content: Routine, header: RoutineHeader }}></Route>
  <Route path="routine/:routine/:day" components={{ content: Day, header: DayHeader }}></Route>
 </Route>
</Router>
```